# Deep Learning Lubuntu vs. Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, python

I am a computer vision researcher, and I am trying to build lightweight programs so that they run quickly on lower-end CPUs. Anyways, I am utilizing a Raspberry Pi, and I would like to compare if Lubuntu would be faster than Ubuntu in running libraries such as Tensorflow and Keras. Moreover, since I do not know much about different Linux systems, can deep learning libraries even be installed on Lubuntu?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking here. Basically any software can be run/installed on (L)Ubuntu, though it certainly helps if there’s a `.deb` package. A package `python3-keras` shipping the deep learning framework is available in the universe repo since 18.04, thus can be installed simply. Does that answer your question?

Comment: *Test and compare :-)* -The main differences between Ubuntu and Lubuntu (and the other flavours of Ubuntu) are 1. the desktop environment and 2. the default application programs. - Lubuntu comes with a lighter desktop environment and lighter application programs. If you install some calculation libraries/programs, you can expect that they work in the same way in Lubuntu as in Ubuntu, because the engine behind the curtain is the same in both cases. If you test and find a difference, it may depend on the available RAM (standard Ubuntu needs more RAM than Lubuntu to run the desktop environment).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is Python 3 also installed by default on Lubuntu just like on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the various *ubuntu is the desktop manager and associated utilities. They have no influence on the execution time of other processes, besides whatever RAM/CPU they use when active, but would you use the desktop intensively on the Rpi?

There are lightweight Linux distros specifically made for the RPi (Raspian et al.) that are normally more fit than a Ubuntu if the Rpi is only meant to run programs developer on another machine (kernel tailored to the Rpi, etc...). Raspian comes with LXDE, so it's fairly close to Lubuntu.